# Does cosmological homogeneity imply that density is also the same?

Tags: astronomy

So I know that at sufficient scales, the universe looks the same (Same average amount of galaxies, clusters, stars, etc). Does this mean that at these scales the density of the universe is also the same?

Comment: Yep............

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all of the components of the stress energy tensor would be the same. That is what homogeneity and isotropy imply.